# Введение неправильного типа не приводит к ошибке

Tags: java, scanner

Есть программа калькулятор. нужно сделать так, чтобы если мы ввели не число, у нас  не выводилась ошибка, а программа говорила попробовать еще раз.

```
class Calculator{
static boolean Action(boolean b){//статический метод
    System.out.println("Введите число"); //ввод с клавиатуры
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    final boolean x= (!sc.hasNextDouble());// константа х
    b=x; //если есть буквы, то b=true и наоборот
    return b;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while (Action(true)){    //если b=true, значит есть буквы и мы вводим сначала, если false, то одни цифры и выход
      System.out.println("попробуйте еще раз");
        if (false) break;} //выход или повтор
    System.out.println("сделано");//выход успешен. программа заверешена
}}
```

проблема в том, что после этого кода я не могу использовать введенное число для арифметических подсчетов

Comment: Зачем вы передаете в `Action` переменную `b`? Вам необходимо разнести логику чтения и валидацию введенных значений. Метод `Action` должен ТОЛЬКО читать и возвращать введенные символы. После этого, в другом методе, эти данные надо проверять на корректность.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот достаточно простой способ добиться того, чего вы хотите. Дальше уже полностью зависит от вашего желания

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            boolean flag = true;
            double value = 0;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            while(flag){
                System.out.println("Введите значение");
                if(sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                    value = sc.nextDouble();
                    flag = false;
                } else{
                    sc.next();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(value);
        }
```